# Can not make a transformation to apply my PCA model

Tags: r, pca

First, I would like to say that I spend hours trying to figure out what's going on with my data, and perhaps there is something that I can not understand about the theory or the required steps.

#### Reading data

Dataset: [uscrime](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/frm1789/datasets/master/uscrime.txt)

```
uscrime <- read.csv('uscrime.txt', header = TRUE, sep = '')
uscrime <- dplyr::mutate_all(uscrime, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
uscrime_pca <- prcomp(uscrime, center = TRUE,scale. = TRUE)
```

#### Using the pcaCharts, I found that I only need k = 5

[image]

#### Creating a simple linear model using PC1 to PC5

using PCs combined with crime data, creating a linear regression model

```
  k  = 5
  uscrime_PCs <- cbind(uscrime_pca$x[,1:k],uscrime[,16])
  model <- lm(V6~., data = as.data.frame(uscrime_PCs))
  summary(model)
```

#### Applying transformation

```
  beta0 <- model$coefficients[1]
  betas <- model$coefficients[2:(k+1)]
  alpha <- uscrime_pca$rotation[,1:k] %*% betas
  mu <- sapply(uscrime[,1:16],mean)
  sigma <- sapply(uscrime[,1:16],sd)
  origAlpha <- alpha/sigma
  origBeta0 <- beta0 - sum(alpha*mu /sigma)
  estimates <- as.matrix(uscrime[,1:16]) %*% origAlpha + origBeta0
```

#### This is the value that I want to calculate with my new model

```
  value_to_be_calculate <- data.frame(M= 14.0, So = 0, Ed = 10.0, Po1 = 12.0, Po2  = 15.5, LF = 0.640, M.F = 94.0, Pop = 150, NW = 1.1, U1 = 0.120, U2 = 3.6, Wealth = 3200, Ineq = 20.1, Prob = 0.040,Time = 39.0)
```

#### This is the part that I can not solve:

```
   pred_df <- data.frame(predict(uscrime_pca, value_to_be_calculate)) 
   pred <- predict(model, pred_df)
```

#### Aditional questions

I am not using in any way `estimates` variable in the calculation regarding with `value_to_be_calculate` with the PCA model

Comment: Your code does not give a reproducible example. Please fix it. Make sure you don't have any remaining objects in your environment. I got multiple errors.

Comment: Checking that right now.

Comment: I have already fixed... I did this: I added an extra value at the end of `value_to_be_calculated` variable. Adding `Crime = 0`, I am really solving the problem, or just making up my mistake?

Comment: First, `alpha` is a 16x1 matrix while `sigma` is a `numeric` of length 16. That's a problem cause you are recycling. Because of that, subsequent objects are non-conformable and I can't execute `estimates <- as.matrix(uscrime[,1:16]) %*% origAlpha + origBeta0`. In addition, what is your desired outcome?

Comment: My desired outcome is calculating the Crime for the `value_to_be_calculate`. Crime is the last column of my dataset `uscrime.txt`